# Metropolitan city adverts/signboards

Tags: texture

I have been scavenging the internet for a long time yet I couldn't find any free packs of any sort pertaining to this specific subject. Anybody know some sites or links to resources leading to signboard textures like these ? The only ones I could find were these Korean street signs [Joost Vanhoutte's gumroad](https://gumroad.com/joost#) but alas its paid.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [unsplash.com](http://unsplash.com). It's awesome site that provides photos that can be used free of charge for commercial and noncommercial purposes.

> All photos published on Unsplash can be used for free. You can use them for commercial and noncommercial purposes. You do not need to ask permission from or provide credit to the photographer or Unsplash, although it is appreciated when possible.

[unsplash.com/license](https://unsplash.com/license)

I made few quick searches and managed to find some pics that could be usefull for you.

https://unsplash.com/search/photos/billboard

https://unsplash.com/search/photos/broadway